# UAC error (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, uac

I have a problem with UAC permission in windows 7 & vista . My application copies it self to C:/file.exe . The problem is the application  says "Access to path is denied" , so I've changed "requestedExecutionLevel" in manifest file to "requireAdministrator" , and it worked well . But I had a problem on UAC disabled machines , it says again " Access to path is denided" , so how I can solve this problem on UAC disabled machines ?

Comment: Your program would have problem running in XP if the user log in using a normal account. Turning off UAC does not grant everyone permission to everywhere, you still have to deal with users who have security in mind and does not want to run under the administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the C:/, actually the driver which the OS is installed to, folder is a protected folder that requires administrator privileges for writing operations. This also happens in some other folders like Program Files folder and its all subfolders.

Thus, simply move your file to somewhere else.

Comment: But if UAC is enabled , this file will be moved after the users permission , if the UAC is disabled , it's supposed to work directly , instead , it says access is denied .